# Write a file into another binary file

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

Like the title says I'm trying to write a file within another binary file, the thing is that the way I do it, it seems that it saves a reference to the original file, not the file itself, anyone knows how can I do save the whole file not just a reference?
here's the code I used:

```
File archivo = new File(name + ".compressing");
BitOS fop = new BitOS(
        new FileOutputStream(archivo));
for (int i = 0; i < secuenciaFinal.length(); i++) {
    if (secuenciaFinal.charAt(i) == '1') {
        fop.write(1);//lee la cadena y si contiene 1 escribe 1 bit en mi archivo
    } else if (secuenciaFinal.charAt(i) == '0') {
        fop.write(0);//si la cadena contiene 0 escribe 0 bits
    }
}
fop.close();
// guardar el árbol y el archivo con la secuencia como binario.
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(name + ".DABCZIP");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(archivo);           
    oos.writeObject(root);
    oos.writeObject(extension);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (oos != null) {
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to save "archivo" in the new file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An ObjectOutputStream writes the state of Java objects.  If `root` and `extension` are Strings, you shouldn't be using an ObjectOutputStream at all.  You also don't need to write a separate file.  You should use a single DataOutputStream, writing to just your DABCZIP file, to write your bit values, the root, and the extension.

Comment: but the root is a class I did I don't see a way to write it with DataOutputStream.

Comment: Then using an ObjectOutputStream may be the correct approach.  You still don't need a separate file;  ObjectOutputStream implements DataOutput, so you have a lot of methods at your disposal.  You can write the length of your binary string using [writeInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeInt-int-), then call ObjectOutputStream's own [write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#write-int-) method directly for each bit value.

Comment: I've got one last question, is it normal that ObjectOutputStream  uses more space than DataOutputStream? I wrote a byte array with both and with ObjectOutputStream  it's size is far bigger, when written with DOS it took 3 bytes, with OOS took 81 bytes...

Comment: Yes, it's normal.  DataOutputStream just writes raw data.  ObjectOutputStream is considerably more complex: it writes the fully qualified class name, the name and value of every non-transient field, and an identifier to prevent the same object being written multiple times and to prevent infinite recursion.  The details are in [the Java Serialization specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).