# Write a file within another file

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

Like the title says I'm trying to write a file within another binary file, the thing is that the way I do it, it seems that it saves a reference to the original file, not the file itself, anyone knows how can I do save the whole file not just a reference?
here's the code I used:

```
File archivo = new File(name + ".compressing");
BitOS fop = new BitOS(
        new FileOutputStream(archivo));
for (int i = 0; i < secuenciaFinal.length(); i++) {
    if (secuenciaFinal.charAt(i) == '1') {
        fop.write(1);//lee la cadena y si contiene 1 escribe 1 bit en mi archivo
    } else if (secuenciaFinal.charAt(i) == '0') {
        fop.write(0);//si la cadena contiene 0 escribe 0 bits
    }
}
fop.close();
// guardar el árbol y el archivo con la secuencia como binario.
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(name + ".DABCZIP");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(archivo);           
    oos.writeObject(root);
    oos.writeObject(extension);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (oos != null) {
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to save "archivo" in the new file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File` is misnamed; a `File` isn't a file, it's only the path to a file (that doesn't even have to exist!). So you need to read the file, and write its contents to the new file.

Comment: ohh I see thanks for clearing that out, I was trying to make the huffman compression so I wanted to store a file that I had saved bit by bit, complete waste of my time, it was really freaking easy using BitSet, wish I had known before that way I wouln't have spent 3 hours trying to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a file into another binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552990/write-a-file-into-another-binary-file)